# Double in a scanner class, How do I get it to work?

Tags: java

This code is having issues with a double appearing in a scanner class, the issue is at the line with the first if statement.  I'm attempting to create a simple calculator for my class, with a limit on the input being 100, if a number is greater than 100 it would set the input to 100 indicating  an upper limit. 
Anyway I'm just stumped and I can't reach my teacher, I've looked up numerous ways on Google, and looked at some old projects as well. The simpler it is the better.

```
    {
        // create a Scanner to obtain input from the command window
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double number1; // first number to add
        double number2; // second number to add
        double sum; // sum of number1 and number2

        System.out.print("Enter first number: "); // prompt
        {
            if ( number1 >= 100 )
            {
                number1 = input.nextDouble("100");
            }

            else if ( number1 <= 100 )
            {
                number1 = input.nextDouble();
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Enter second number: "); // prompt
        number2 = input.nextDouble(); // read second number from user

        sum = number1 + number2; // add numbers, then store total in sum

        System.out.printf("Sum is %.0f\n", sum); // display sum
    }
} // end class Addition
```

Comment: Right now, your if statements are checking an uninitialized variable. call `input.nextDouble()` and then check the resulting double to see if it's in the range you want. If not, change it to 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the value of `number1` before assigning a value to it. This should give you the following error *"Variable 'number1' might not have been initialized"*.

You could use `Math.min` to set a ceiling, so that `number1` will be at most 100:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter first number: "); // prompt
double number1 = Math.min(input.nextDouble(), 100); // first number to add

System.out.print("Enter second number: "); // prompt
double number2 = input.nextDouble(); // read second number from user

double sum = number1 + number2; // add numbers, then store total in sum

System.out.printf("Sum is %.0f\n", sum); // display sum
```

As a side note, it is good practice to declare the variables as close as possible to where you are going to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that you are using the variable before it is intitialized.

double number1;
...
if ( number1 >= 100 )

There is no value assigned to number1

Comment: Thanks, but it seemed to work just fine for the other classes/methods.

Answer (score 0):

All these variables are **Local Variables**  and as local variables don't have any default value you need to initialize them  before use

```
    double number1; // All three of them are not initialized 
    double number2; 
    double sum;
```

So either use

```
 number1=input.getDouble();
 if(number1>100){
 // do whatever you want to do
 }
 else{
      // do whatever you want to do
 }
```

Or **Initialize them**

Comment: Thanks, but it seemed to work just fine for the other classes/methods, in terms of initialization.